# How to remove radio button checked attribute from previously selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have some radio buttons and I am adding checked attribute to selected radio button but having one problem. I want to remove checked="checked" attribute from radio button which selected.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="tabtwo-info">
    <div class="tab-two">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Unsecured Loans
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Secured 2nd Charge Lending
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Overdrafts
                    </div>
                </div>
             </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="seperator">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">   <span class="sep"></span>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Trade Finance
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Business Cash Advance
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Working Capital
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="seperator">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">   <span class="sep"></span>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Stock Finance
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">   <a class="brokersector" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="radio" value="" id="" name="brokersector">
                <div class="image-cat-box">
                    <div class="image-box">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-cat">
                        Acquisition Finance
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="seperator">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">   <span class="sep"></span>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(".tabtwo-info .brokersector").click(function () {
    $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jj57q8fs/

JSFiddle Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: add a jsFiddle please

Comment: You don't need to do this - by setting one as selected the others are automatically de-selected. There is no JS required.

Comment: @JoeFitter I have added jsfiddle. `https://jsfiddle.net/jj57q8fs/`

Comment: What is the problem? It is anyways unchecking the previous radios.

Comment: @ShaunakD Check my JSFiddle. `checked="checked"` is not removing when I checked to another radio button.

Comment: The jsFiddle works as expected

Comment: You can use $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', false); to uncheck

Comment: Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/jj57q8fs/1/. Though removing the attribute or keeping it as is won't make any difference.

Comment: @JoeFitter I have checked in my fiddle and its not working. Checked screenshot in question. Thanks

Comment: @Manan there is big difference between `checked` attribute and `checked` property. Check an example with property changing: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj57q8fs/2/).

Comment: May be I can't explain well in my question but I just want to remove ` all checked="checked"` in radio button if I selected previously.

Comment: @Manan what about not touching `checked` attribute at all? Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @Regent May be I can't explain well in my question but I just want to remove ` all checked="checked"` in radio button if I selected previously.

Comment: @Manan no need to post the same text twice. Once again: as you can see in my fiddle, I neither add `checked` attribute nor I delete it. If you **do not add `checked` attribute** to element, you **do not have to remove it** from element at all.

Answer (score 6):

To force a remove of the attribute, before checking a new:

```
$(".brokersector").click(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

This will force an removal of all `checked` on any radio button, before a new radio is set. The selector can be more specific of course, like in Idir's example.

Also, @Regent [posted a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj57q8fs/2/) using `prop` instead. I would suggest you use this, as it states in the documentation:

> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be **used only to set the initial value of the checkbox**. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does.

Comment: I cant find checked="checked" from radio button when I select to radio option.

Comment: @Manan as I have already mentioned in question's comments, don't mess `checked` attribute and `checked` property

Comment: @Manan I actually saw the same thing in your fiddle, but could not reproduce it here on SO. See my update at the top. It worked fine on your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```js
$(".tabtwo-info .brokersector").click(function() {
  $('input[name=brokersector]').removeAttr('checked');
  $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Rory McCrossan][1], you don't need jQuery for that. but here is what you can do this:

```
$('input[name=brokersector]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".tabtwo-info .brokersector").click(function () {
$("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});


});
```